# How to Split the input data to ItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Requirement is to update details of all the given employee numbers (probably around 100k) by invoking Rest endpoint.

I am having a custom reader/processor and writer using spring batch

1. Reader will invoke a POST API (/get/employeDetails) which requires
   list of employeeNumbers as input
2. processor will convert the List to List
3. Writer will invoke an PATCH API(/update/dept)

here i would like to invoke the POST API in a batch wise because POST API cannot handle all the load for a given 100k so would like to invoke like below.

Thread 1 - invoke POST API for having employee numbers 1- 10
Thread 2 - invoke POST API for having employee numbers 11- 20
Thread 3 - invoke POST API for having employee numbers 21- 30 and so on .

I tried having partitioner but not able to  split the input to POST API , any idea on how to achieve using spring batch

Comment: `I tried having partitioner but not able to split the input`: What is the input you need to partition? Can you share the partitioner you tried? Does the API accept a single ID or a list of IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You must add an endpoint that gets the employeeIds in chunk and then call the other endpoint that gets the details. Your reader must implement itemStream to keep trace of your offset and chunk and propagate this values in the executionContext.

```
@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    executionContext.putLong("chunk", this.chunk);
    executionContext.putLong("offset", this.offset);
}

@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    this.chunk = executionContext.getLong("chunk");
    this.offset = executionContext.getLong("offset");
}
```